# Select records between a date in d-mY format and 1rst of next month, plus 1 day in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to select all data from a table '**followup**' between followup_date and first of next month (including 1rst of next month). The format of my date in DB (obtained from an API) is **d-m-Y**.

The `follow-up date` for example is: **18-07-2020**.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * from followup 
WHERE DATEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(`followup_date`,'%d-%m-%Y'), DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH,'%Y-%m-01'))- 1 < 0 ;
```

I am getting -15 days as difference and getting records correctly, including 1rst. Is the query **correct and efficient** and will it work correctly for all months.

Requesting suggestions from experts for improvements, if any.

Comment: A couple of options: either store dates using a date data type, or don't bother with an RDBMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert your `followup_date` column to a `DATE` type. You can then make your query [sargable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable) by removing the function calls on `followup_date` and simply comparing it with the target date:

```
SELECT * from followup 
WHERE `followup_date` <= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH,'%Y-%m-01')
```

I suspect adding one day to `LAST_DAY(CURDATE())` might be more efficient:

```
SELECT * from followup 
WHERE `followup_date` <= LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f4c51/2)

Comment: @Pamela sorry about that - I have fixed both.

Comment: @Pamela I've added a demo of both queries

Comment: So the second query is more efficient. Execution Time: 1ms compared with 8ms for first . Thank you so much..

Comment: @Pamela that's interesting to know that a lot of the slowdown was in the `DATE_FORMAT`. I'll keep it in mind for future queries.